# react-native simulator stuck after BUNDLE Loading

Tags: react-native

This was loading.  Stopped the simulator, rebooted computer and now it builds and gets stuck after the BUNDLE is done.

Loading dependency graph, done.
BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (585/585), done.

I've disabled active debugging.
I've removed and reinstalled node_modules
I've removed ios/build/*

I'm not seeing any other errors, but i'm not sure where to find logs when launching from react-native.

I'm running
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.54.4